# ESC doesn't work in cygwin vim

Tags: vim, windows-7, cygwin, keyboard-shortcuts

I installed cygwin on Windows 7. When I start vim in cygwin terminal it starts in interactive mode. I can't change mode to command one by pressing ESC. What could be the reason?

---

**UPDATE:**
Also vim prints these varnings at start:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Answer (score 6):

If by *interactive mode* you mean *insert mode* (where keypresses are inserted as text, just as in other editors), then your Vim is in *easy mode*.

In it, you can temporarily execute normal mode commands via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>. But I guess you don't want this strange beginner's mode. To turn it off, check whether Vim has been invoked with the `-y` argument or as `evim` (is there a shell alias?). Or, if you find a `:set insertmode` command in a `.vimrc`, remove it. (By default, at least in my Cygwin installations, Vim is not configured for easy mode, so it must be something in your configuration.)

Comment: I've just installed cygwin and there are no any config for vim. My home directory is empty. I think the problem is that vim can't get ESC code. When I press arrows A, B, C and D are appearing in buffer. But in bash that keys do what they intended to do.

Comment: But you said it "starts in interactive mode". If just Esc wouldn't work, you would still have to (once) enter insert mode via `i`. Anyway, if it's the Escape key, try leaving insert mode via Ctrl-\ Ctrl-N.

Answer (score 1):

Try to 
Press “ESC” and "shift" and ":" together;
You should find the place that you can type command line in vim；